# Oracle AWR Report file can not be written to the disk (using Oracle Database Server Docker Image)

Tags: oracle, docker, spool, awr

I am trying to generate an AWR report in Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production (using Oracle Database Server Docker Image).

I am connected to the DB as sysdba.
In sqlplus I run: @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql, after answering output format(html), starting and ending snapshot, and output file name I got an output:

Using the report name awrrpt_1_1_4.html

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "awrrpt_1_1_4.html"
```

Obviously I can not find the file awrrpt_1_1_4.html on path `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/`

I got enough space:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          59G   13G   43G  23% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        59G   13G   43G  23% /ORCL
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
```

For the output directory `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/` I gave `chmod 777`, I can also create a file and put some data into it and save it with vi editor.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

why are you changing permissions of Oracle DB's own directories? Just do it in your home dir

create directory /home/oracle/myWorkspace

then execute your script using spool, and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Cause: The STORE command was unable to create the specified file. There may be insufficient disk space, too many open files, or read-only protection on the output directory.

Action: Check that there is sufficient disk space and that the protection on the directory allows file creation.